# Exception is caught but procedure also working

Tags: java

im looking at some code for an upload method on uploading the file to the server. I have an int variable and for every catch, it is incremented. At the end of the code, the count is zero, meaning there were no exceptions caught, however, the output that occurs shows that the last exception(exception e) was caught. The result is, at first the result is that it is uploaded, then is says the exception was caught so upload failed. I'm a beginner android developer so any help is greatly appreciated.

Example Code:

```
catch(exception e){
   count ++
   //does something that shows that upload was not successful there has been an exception.
}
finally{
   if (count==0){
   //show that the upload was successful 
   }
}
```

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile. It's hard to know what's wrong with your *real* code without showing it. Please cut it down to a minimal example which demonstrates the problem but is still valid code.

Comment: @JonSkeet...I don't have access to the codes right now, so I typed what i remember. My main question is why the count is zero but an exception is still being caught? Any ideas on why that is happening?? Thank You

Comment: No, I have no idea why that's happening, because I can't see the code. That's my point. I suggest you delete this question if you still can, and post a new one with *real* code when you're in a position to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the scope of count is defined properly.
to be sure make it a global variable.

Comment: this is not a proper aswer, it should be a comment, since you can´t comment yet, try to answer questions in a correct way or leave it.

Comment: By downvoting his answer though, it will be even longer for j l to be able to comment (and help constructively). I upvoted this as this practice discourages new users. The comment @luk2302 left is sufficient to educate the user going forward.